# jquery parseXML giving invalid XML error

Tags: jquery, xml, parsexml

I am getting an invalid XML error when using $.parseXML() with my string of XML data. The string is:

```
<query_result>
    <row id=1>
        <distance>2.835</distance>
        <post_title>anywhere</post_title>
        <post_excerpt></post_excerpt>
        <ID>425</ID>
    </row>
    <row id=2>
        <distance>2.862</distance>
        <post_title>nowhere</post_title>
        <post_excerpt></post_excerpt>
        <ID>435</ID>
    </row>
    <row id=3>
        <distance>2.867</distance>
        <post_title>who knows</post_title>
        <post_excerpt></post_excerpt>
        <ID>429</ID>
    </row>
</query_result>
```

I can't seem to find the reason I am getting this error. anyone care to share some insight?
Thanks a lot in advance.
EDIT: changed the xml to allow root brackets to match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The opening and closing Tag of the outermost Element do not Match (`query_result` vs. `result`).

The `row` elements' `id` attribute values need to be enclosed in double or single quotes.
A well-formed XML document also needs a so-called 'prologue' as the very first line of the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Comment: I applied this and it is still giving me the same error

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help. It now works as it should. Hope it wasn't too much of a bother...

Answer (score 0):

You need to include your attribute values in quotes, e.g. `<row id="1">`.  See this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_attributes.asp) for additional information.